# Querying total data by months in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have an issue getting the lists of all months and the totals of corresponding data sorted according to the months.

I have tried a method which only return a dictionary of the current month as well as the total of all data irrespectively of whether it falls on that month or not.

This is the query i have written for it

```
po = {
    'sales_sum': Sum('po_amount'),
}

queryset2 = PurchaseOrder.objects.values('created_on__month').annotate(**po).order_by('created_on__month')
```

This method return the queryset below

```
<QuerySet [{'created_on__month': 9, 'sales_sum': Decimal('429670')}]>
```

But i wanted a key value pair like ("jan":50000, "feb":60000,"mar":70000) for all months and totals

This is my model

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
po_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

This is newly added view that displays the date on the terminal

```
po = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()

for i in po:
    print(i.created_on)
```

This is the result on the terminal showing th actual date:

```
2020-09-23 20:06:21.844422
2020-09-23 06:51:39.649277
2020-09-22 08:15:04.151440
2020-09-22 08:13:32.788178
2020-09-22 07:32:04.902845
2020-09-21 23:39:57.368652
2020-09-21 23:33:13.513847
2020-09-19 21:00:47.138431
2020-09-17 18:37:54.993158
2020-09-16 23:59:03.696993
2020-09-16 23:58:10.961369
2020-09-16 23:57:19.276851
2020-09-13 21:23:25.573395
2020-09-13 07:53:38.698313
2020-09-13 07:52:28.252597
```

This is the way i create my purchase order using a modelform:

[image: The image showing my create_purchase_order_page]

The image showing my purchase order list after creation

[image: purchase order list page]

I hope i can get a solution to this
Thanks
Oyero

Comment: Well you only have sales for september, so it will only yield values for september.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you only have sales for September, so it will only yield values for September. But you can do some post-processing to construct a mapping:

```
from datetime import date
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db.models import Sum

queryset2 = PurchaseOrder.objects.values('created_on__month').annotate(
    sales_sum=Sum('po_amount')
).order_by('created_on__month')

data = {
    r['created_on__month']: r['sales_sum'] for r in queryset2
}

zero = Decimal(0)

data = {
    datetime.date(1900, m, 1).strftime('%b'): data.get(m, zero)
    for m in range(1, 13)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the contribution sir

Comment: My computer is dead, I will try it when the power is back.

Comment: Thanks so much sir,

I was able to a dictionary of all months and a total po, but the current issue is that all purchase order created irrespective of the month created only stores on september(the current month), which actually is supposed to store on its corresponding month.

Am i missing anything please.

Comment: Also more importantly, when i used the queryset as you have written it
"queryset2 = PurchaseOrder.objects.values('created_on__month').annotate(sales_sum: Sum('po_amount')).order_by('created_on__month')", i get an error of "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" wherby the arror/error seems to come from "sales_sum"

So,  ihad to change it to
"queryset2 = PurchaseOrder.objects.values('created_on__month').annotate(**po).order_by('created_on__month')" where my po is " po = {
        'sales_sum': Sum('po_amount'),
    }"

What do you think might be wrong Sir
Thanks

Comment: Okay seems i was able to fix that. The queryset was supposed to be
"queryset2 = PurchaseOrder.objects.values('created_on__month').annotate(sales_sum= Sum('po_amount')).order_by('created_on__month')"

It was supposed to be an equal to sign after "sales_sum" instead of a colon.

Comment: @king_bibah: aargghhh yes. Sorry I made a typo. Does the post-processing works?

Comment: Yes, it does sir

But the only issue is that all payment created irrespectively of the mootns all appends to to the the current month

Comment: @king_bibah: but is there data for _other_ months?

Comment: Yes sir. I added data to other months so a to test it but it kept aggregating the the current month September

Comment: Is it okay if I share the GitHub repo or I shouldn't bother

Comment: @king_bibah: are you sure it is saved that way in the database?

Comment: @king_bibah: note that the `auto_now_add`, will be default take the *current* timestamp. So in order to create historical data, you will need to override that, right?

Comment: Okay Sir, I will confirm that

Comment: I checked the database and it reflects the correct month and time that I have added which were the following months after it

Comment: Hi Sir, I just checked the dates in the terminal and noticed that the time was the current time not the one I input

Comment: The auto_now_add overrode it and then the month was still September although I put a different month

Comment: @king_bibah: but how did you *input* it? Normally you *can* override this, but I'm wondering how you do that. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64018818/67579) the question and add how you create records?

Comment: How can I write a function to override that and get historical data as you have said sir

Comment: I will add the image diagram to give a better idea

Comment: @Willwm Van Onsem, i have edited the question showing the recent changes in development, hopefully we can get a solution now.

Comment: @king_bibah: but your `ModelForm` does not contains a `created_on` field?

Comment: I have been so stupid all day, i just noticed that i have been filtering by created_on instead of order_date which i specify 

Thanks a lot for help all day, i can't thank you completely.

Am so grateful

Comment: now i get the right queryset "{'Jan': Decimal('0'), 'Feb': Decimal('0'), 'Mar': Decimal('0'), 'Apr': Decimal('0'), 'May': Decimal('0'), 'Jun': Decimal('30000'), 'Jul': Decimal('0'), 'Aug': Decimal('0'), 'Sep': Decimal('309670'), 'Oct': Decimal('100000'), 'Nov': Decimal('70000'), 'Dec': Decimal('60000')}"

Comment: Please Sir, kindly help me look into this issues i am having, the link is below,

https://stackoverflow.com/q/64235792/13255031